# Catch TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel

Sometimes, when `laravel_session` cookie expired and I'm still on the page, I would log in and get the `TokenMismatchException` error. This is understandable.

I would like to handle this case, e.g. by showing some kind of error to the user and redirecting. If possible, I would like to catch it only for the login request.

The main problem is that the CSRF token is checked by a global middleware, so the error gets thrown before I can handle it with `try-catch` block in a controller action.

Another problem is that the **VerifyCsrfToken.php** in the `app/Http/Middeware` directory, which looks like this:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];
}
```

I can't see how I could use the code above to catch the `TokenMismatchException`. Seems like I can only exclude specific URIs.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Do you really have users idle for N hours who then want to use the application? Extend the session time then.

Comment: If you caught TokenMismatchException, you put yourself at security risk. It makes no sense.

Comment: I would preferably catch the exception only for the login request, not globally. Also, extending session time is not a solution for me. The session is set to 2 hours, and there are users who still have this problem.

Comment: Then make a middleware that redirects users with the invalidated session to the login page before token mismatch could happen. Before login, there's no session created, so there could be no error with this.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **app\Exceptions\Handler.php** and test it like this:

```
//Add this to render() method:

if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
   return $this->handleTokenMismatchException($exception);
}

// then...

protected function handleTokenMismatchException(TokenMismatchException $exception) {

    // What you gonna do about it e.g. return redirect('/somewhere');

}
```

Comment: As it was noted, it's apparently a duplicate from my side, but the answer is valid. Thanks!